# How to make php open gui application on a ubuntu desktop

Tags: php, ubuntu, command-line-interface

This might seem so very weird but, I just want to open a gui application on ubuntu using php comamnds.

I've tried with the below commands but it didnt work.

```
$output = exec("gedit"); 

echo $output;
```

also

```
system()
```

and

```
passthru()
```

My point of view might really seem like very annoying. But I want to get this done for some reason. Thanks for any help..

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a good diagnosis. What errors do you get? Anything written to any log files? What research have you done into invoking processes from within PHP?

Comment: when i run the php file, it shows nothing.

Comment: i mean, nothing happens at all.
Just a blank page ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

This code works on osx:

```
<?php

exec('open /Volumes');
```

Run:

```
php test.php
```

You cannot run gui app from website, because x server is not available there.

Comment: what if i wanna do the same on linux(ubuntu)?